# In the calendar function "date(byAdding: .day, value: , to: )", does the date we give to the function include the current date or not?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have an app that uses Core Data. I have a function

```
func showHistory(for days:Int)->Int {

        var historyForXDaysInt = Int()

        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.locale = .current
        calendar.timeZone = .current

        var startDate:Date?
        var endDate = Date()

        switch days{
        case 1:
            startDate = Date()
            startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: startDate!)

        default:

           startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -days+1, to: Date())
           startDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: startDate!)

        }
//There is more to this function, where I make the request but I just included the relevant part for my question
}
```

My question: I am trying to get relevant data from Core Data between two dates via the predicate `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(completedDate >= %@) AND (completedDate <= %@)", startDate! as NSDate, endDate as NSDate)`.There is a completedDate property in my core data model. When I make the request I get data for 1 more day than I asked for. I tried solving it with adding 1 to the days variable. For example, if I am asking for 2 days of data (meaning days = 2) I get data for 3 days. What might be the cause? Why does it not work as intended without the +1 ?

Comment: It's because the time zone is involved, try `calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just tried it. I deleted the +1 in my code and added TimeZone as you suggested. Still does the same thing...1 More day problem...